# What type of statistics test should I use?

Tags: statistical-significance, categorical-data, binomial-distribution

I'm investigating the prevalence of a specific disease in 4 cohorts; symptomatic male, symptomatic female, asymptomatic male, asymptomatic females.

I've tested the samples and have positive/negative results for each sample:

I would like to check if age, gender, and symptomatic status has any influence on the detection of disease.

I'm not great at SPSS, how should I input the data and what test would I best use?

Thanks!

Comment: How to input data into SPSS is off-topic here. Please see advice in the Help Center on software-specific questions. Otherwise, have you looked at previous questions under your tags? This kind of question is routine for epidemiology or medical statistics/biostatistics texts and courses.

Comment: Hi Nick thanks for your reply. Yes i have a rough idea of what to do but I was looking for a more experienced opinion to make sure I was not missing anything :)

Comment: If your response is binary you would presumably looking at something like logistic regression.

Comment: As a start, can  you provide four counts in a $2 \times 2$ table for Men; Symptomatic; Yes/No; Postive Test: Yes/No? There are various tests for such tables, binomial, chi-squared, and Fisher exact. (To check 'predictability'.) // Maybe you know how to use SPSS to get the counts. Once you have the table, software is not really necessary. // Then a similar table for Women, and another for everyone. That may not be the end of the analysis, but could give you a good idea what to explore next.